# Could high dosage Omega-3 oils reduce COVID-19 pneumonia?

Tags: covid-19, coronavirus, omega-3, pneumonia, anti-inflammatory

I understand that Omega-3 oils have anti-inflammatory properties.

At high daily dose (say 5 grams) could they reduce the dangerous COVID-19 related pneumonia seen in some patients?

I guess one would have to be careful of bleeding problems if the dose is too high.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Answer (score 2):

A very recent Cochrane review of the use of Omega 3 in ARDS, not specifically from COVID-19, did not find any benefit using trials up to 2018.

> **Conclusions**: This Cochrane meta-analysis of 10 studies of varying quality examined the effects of omega-3 fatty acids and antioxidants in adults with ARDS. This intervention may produce little or no difference in all-cause mortality between groups. We are uncertain whether immunonutrition with omega-3 fatty acids and antioxidants improves ventilator days, ICU length of stay, or oxygenation due to the very low quality of evidence.

Immunonutrition for Adults With ARDS: Results From a Cochrane Systematic Review and Meta-Analysis
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31506339/

Answer (score 0):

Here is Oregon State, Linus Pauling Institute. Immunity In Brief. They begin with Omega 3 to help reduce inflammation. I don’t think they give a dose, I don’t remember. Personally I would follow the label directions which are going to tell you to consult your doctor before taking if you are on medications, (and I would say particularly for a dose of 5 grams. ). https://lpi.oregonstate.edu/mic/health-disease/immunity-in-brief  If you are 60 or over, or have some other problem, then I think it would be even more important to consult your doctor first. https://lpi.oregonstate.edu/mic/health-disease/immunity-in-brief

Remember Vitamin E and A can give some “thinning” and so can many herbal products. And obviously one must take into account other OTC products like aspirin and other NSAIDs.

This just addresses Immunity in Brief according to the above article and not whether this will help prevent pneumonia in association with COVID 19, since the FDA is very strict on supplements being touted for COVID19.

Bottom line:  consult your doctor first. They know your medical history.

PS to be more specific the OSU article says, “EPA and DHA have an overall anti-inflammatory effect.”   see the link.